# Differential Backup from SQL Server 2012 to Azure Blob

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup, azure-blob-storage

I am attempting to backup a database to my Azure Blob storage. The databases are relatively large... between 1 and 30 Gig.

I have successfully backed up the first day, but on subsequent days, I get an error stating that the file already exists and that I need to use the WITH FORMAT.

But I need to do a differential backup, as the load of data on a full backup would be very slow and pricey.

I get the error "MyBackup.bak exists on the remote endpoint, and WITH FORMAT was not specified.".

What I am trying to do is:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [MyDatabase]' 
TO URL = 'https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/dbbackups/Container/', MyDatabase.bak', 
WITH CREDENTIAL = 'AzureDBBackupsContainer'
, DIFFERENTIAL
, COMPRESSION;
```

I have seen that a differential backup is supported when using URL backups.

Is this actually not possible, or am I doing something wrong? Do I need to somehow change the file name each day?

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, this is not possible in Azure cloud. You can do this for premise backup which I highly discourage. It just makes your restore more complicated. But in Azure if file name already exists in your container only way to use that same name is to use `WITH FORMAT` which will create a new media set.

I tested this and I get following error message:

> Msg 3296, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The file
>   https://storageacocunt/sqlbackfiles/testFull.bak
>   exists on the remote endpoint, and WITH FORMAT was not specified.
>   Backup cannot proceed. Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 BACKUP
>   DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

From Books online:

[BACKUP (Transact-SQL) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-transact-sql)

> FORMAT
>
> Specifies that a new media set be created. FORMAT causes the
>   backup operation to write a new media header on all media volumes used
>   for the backup operation. The existing contents of the volume become
>   invalid, because any existing media header and backup sets are
>   overwritten.

You can check this with `RESTORE HEADERONLY` command. If you take a fullbackup and then a differential `WITH FORMAT`, you will see backup type change from 1 to 5.

I suggest you create a new for each file.

This [link](https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/create-daily-database-backups-with-unique-names-in-sql-server/) has example about generating a new filename for each backup.